# SwiftUI: specifying the minimum width of a .background Capsule

Tags: swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI and trying to create a simple badge view (i.e., text inside a capsule). I also want to ensure that the capsule is at least as wide as it is high.

The following mostly works, except that the text is not centered in the capsule.

Without the geometry reader I can either drop the `.frame` but end up with a capsule that is too narrow if the text is short. Or, I can include the frame with `minWidth` set to a constant, but that won't respond well to any kind of adaptive layout.

I am looking for either another approach to calculating the minimum width, or a way to ensure that the text is centered in the capsule embedded in a geometry reader, but haven't been able to find the correct incantation.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Badge: View {
  let text: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(verbatim: text)
      .font(.caption2)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .padding(2)
      .border(.black.opacity(0.25))
      .background {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
          Capsule()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(minWidth: proxy.size.height)
        }
      }
  }
}

struct Badge_previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 30) {
      Badge(text: "1")
      Badge(text: "10")
      Badge(text: "100")
      Badge(text: "1000")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI.Layout is another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using specifying a negative x offset for the capsule if the text's height exceeds its width. Specifically:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
  Capsule()
    .fill(.red)
    .frame(minWidth: proxy.size.height)
    .offset(
      x: proxy.size.width >= proxy.size.height ? 
        0 : -(proxy.size.height - proxy.size.width) / 2
    )
}
```